# Pandas Dataframe: Calculate Shared Fraction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe, `df`, consisting of a class of two objects, `S`, a set of co-ordinates associated with them, `X` and `Y`, and a value, `V`, that was measured there.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
S X Y V
0 1 1 1
1 2 2 1
1 9 9 2
0 9 9 8
```

I would like to know the commands that allow me to go from this picture to the one where each `S` is converted to a series of columns where:

- `V_s` represents the sum of all the shared `X-Y` coordinates;
- `F0` and `F1` represent the fractions of the V for each possible class, `S`.

For example:

```
X Y V_s  F0  F1
1 1 1  1.0 0.0
2 2 1  0.0 1.0
9 9 10 0.2 0.8
```

I can sum and fraction calculate the fraction by using

```
df['V_s'] = df.groupby(['X', 'Y'])['V'].transform('sum')
df['F'] = df['V']/df['V_s']
```

What are the next steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
(df.groupby(['X','Y','S']).sum()
   .unstack('S', fill_value=0)['V']
   .rename(columns=lambda x: f"F{x}")
   .assign(V_s=lambda x: x.sum(1),
           F0 =lambda x: x['F0']/x['V_s'],
           F1 =lambda x: x['F1']/x['V_s'])
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
S  X  Y   F0   F1  V_s
0  1  1  1.0  0.0    1
1  2  2  0.0  1.0    1
2  9  9  0.8  0.2   10
```

**Update** for unknown/large number of classes in `S`:

```
new_df = (df.groupby(['X','Y','S']).sum()
   .unstack('S', fill_value=0)['V']
   .rename(columns=lambda x: f"F{x}")
)

vs = new_df.sum(1)
new_df = (new_df.div(vs,axis='rows')
                .assign(V_s=vs)
                .reset_index()
         )
```

And you get same output.

Comment: Is there any way to extend the assign part to N fractions? Suppose, if I do not know the dimensionality of S?

Comment: Heroic effort. Thank you from someone who knows little about dataframes!